# Number of allocations of goods to agents

Tags: combinatorics

There is a set $N=\{1,\dots, n\}$ of $n$ agents and a set $M=\{a_1,\dots,a_m\}$ of goods. An allocation of goods to agents is a a function $\pi\colon N\rightarrow 2^M$ such that each item in $M$ is allocated to an agent, and no item gets allocated to more than one agent.

For instance, if there are two agents (i.e., $N=\{1,2\}$) and two goods (i.e., $M=\{a_1,a_2\}$), then the possible allocations are 
$\pi_1=(\emptyset, \{a_1,a_2\})$,
$\pi_2=(\{a_1\}, \{a_2\})$,
$\pi_3=(\{a_2\}, \{a_1\})$ and
$\pi_4=(\{a_1,a_2\}, \emptyset)$.

My question is if there is anything interesting to be said, more generally, about the number of allocations of $m$ goods to $n$ agents. Do these numbers ring a bell? Are they studied? Do they have a name?

I've done some back of the envelope calculations, but was wondering whether there is anything like a neat formula for the general case.

Comment: If you can distinguish elements of $M$ and distinguish elements of $N$, then it is just $n^m$.  If not, look at things like the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) $p_k$.

Comment: Ah, of course: every allocation corresponds to a function from $M$ to $N$ (I made a mistake when counting on a concrete example and it threw me off). Ugh, thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

To me it would seem more natural to consider an allocation as a function $\pi:M\to N$ (each good is assigned to one and only one agent). There is no restriction on what function may be used.  In the formulation in the original post (an allocation is a function from $N$ to the power set of $M$) there are restrictions on the function.

Using the $M\to N$ framework it is clear that the number of allocations is $n^m$.

Comment: I agree, but the idea here is that agents can get assigned bundles of goods, over which they can have preferences, utilities and so on. I got the notion of an allocation by reading some lecture notes on fair division of indivisible goods (Section 5 of U. Endriss. [Lecture Notes on Fair Division](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.04234.pdf)), and just started thinking if we can count these allocations.